# How to refactor this blocking code to non blocking for node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to refactor this code to non blocking.

I have wrote a simple helper code, What this does is generates invoice Number based on provided previous number.

**helper.js**

```
module.exports = {
  replaceCharAt: function replaceCharAt(string, index, character){
    var string = string.split('');
    string[index] = character;
    return string.join('');
  },
  generateInvoiceNumber: function generateInvoiceNumber(invoiceNumber, useIndex){
    var invoiceNumber = invoiceNumber.trim();
    if(typeof useIndex === 'undefined' || useIndex === -1 ){
      useIndex = invoiceNumber.length - 1;
    }
    var incrementChar = invoiceNumber[useIndex];
    if(incrementChar == '9' || incrementChar == 'z' || incrementChar == 'Z'){
      if(incrementChar == 9){
        invoiceNumber = this.replaceCharAt(invoiceNumber, useIndex, '0');
      }
      else{
        invoiceNumber = this.replaceCharAt(invoiceNumber, useIndex, 'a');
      }
      if(useIndex === 0){
        return invoiceNumber = '1'+invoiceNumber;
      }
      return this.generateInvoiceNumber(invoiceNumber, useIndex - 1);
    }
    else{
      var replaceChar = String.fromCharCode(incrementChar.charCodeAt(0) + 1);
      invoiceNumber = this.replaceCharAt(invoiceNumber, useIndex, replaceChar);
    }
    return invoiceNumber;
  }
};
```

How I use it in request handler.

```
var helper = require('./helper');

var handler = function(request, reply){
  var newNumber = helper.generateInvoiceNumber(request.params.oldNumber);
  reply({newNumber: newNumber});
}
```

So this code blocks until it generates the Invoice number. I need some tips and hints on how to refactor this to not block.

Comment: There is no IO in that function, so I don't see any use of converting it to use callbacks/promises or so.

Comment: I was confused on if this would block as it is using recursion to generate invoice number.

Comment: I guess this will be really fast though, so no need to make this async right?

Comment: Ultimately you can't do that unless you move the code into a child process, it's only I/O operations that are non-blocking in Node, Node itself is blocking. [This article](http://greenash.net.au/thoughts/2012/11/nodejs-itself-is-blocking-only-its-io-is-non-blocking/) might give you a better understanding on the differences.

Comment: Do you recommend using child process for this code? or is it really not required here?

Comment: @Yalamber if you need it to be non-blocking in that particular Node process then it's really your only option. For example, you could write a webservice which you can query from your Node process for the next invoice number - this would result in a non-blocking operation given a web request is I/O bound.

Comment: @James But again the webservice process(which will also be on node.js) that generates the invoice number will be blocking right? Say if Many people generates InvoiceNumber at once. It will be blocking right? What I think is this does not matter as this operation will be quite fast for the limited number of character. Invoice Number may not be more than 10-11 character. So it may be good they way it is. Am I right?

Comment: @Yalamber if you went down the route of just spawning a new child process then yes it would also block which, all you are doing here is moving the bottleneck. The best approach would be to have an external system generate the invoice number e.g. a database script, batch file, or even a multi-threaded web service i.e. ASP.NET / PHP etc.

Comment: @James How about I do it this way, I write a new node.js/php or any executable separate script and run it through child_process.exec? will it be non blocking then?

Comment: @Yalamber the main Node process would become non-blocking yes, however, as per my previous comment you would be shifting the bottleneck from one process to another. The code you have is CPU intensive therefore in a single-threaded environment like Node it *has* to block at some point, by moving the code into a child process this means the calling process can continue to receive requests but ultimately it can only work as fast as the child process. The most scalable solution would be to look at a proper multi-threaded environment for your CPU intensive code.

Comment: When I call child process this way
child_process.execFile('/usr/local/bin/node', ['/home/user/generateNumber.js', 'invoiceNumber'], function(error, stdout, stderr){
 console.log(stdout);
});
Does not this run that script without blocking? I mean I could place this code in request handler and take the new generated invoice number from stdout? Will it still be blocking if I do it this way?

Comment: I will actually try and check if it blocks or not. May be it will help me understand event loops and process more clearly. Thank you for the help @James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your code is all synchronous by nature, eg: you're not making any IO calls, there's no way for you to make this code async :(

Async code must be making IO calls, stuff like this:

- Writing to disk.
- Talking over the network.
- Calling subprocesses and waiting for responses.

These things can all be made asynchronous because your program is simply waiting for some other piece of hardware to do something: process results, send responses, etc.

In your code, you're simply performing some CPU operations: if statements, string comparisons, etc. This stuff always has to be processed by your CPU directly, and since that's the case, there's no way for you to 'wait for that to finish', so to speak.

If you're really intent on making this async, you could do the following:

- Write an API service that performs those synchronous tasks.
- Expose that API service over the network: http://blah.com/api
- Rewrite your local Node code to make async calls to that API and wait for the results.

The truth, however, is that since your code is pretty minimally synchronous, you shouldn't need to do the above. All projects have some synchronous code in them -- there's no escaping it =)